# Get sequence of adjacent cell numbers out of a raster

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am currently working on a script, that loads a TIF file into a raster object, crops it and plots two points (starting point and point of destination; selected via the `click`-function) into that raster. I then want it to get the cell numbers of those two points. All of that hasn't caused any trouble but now I have tried to write a while-Loop which gets me the number of a random cell (which is adjacent to the current cell; beginning from the starting point) until that cell number equals the cell number of my point of destination. My idea behind that was to "walk" across the raster until I have reached my point of destination or at least the column containing it (to reduce computation time). The numbers of the cells i cross during that walk should be stored in a vector ("Path"). I select the adjacent cell (=choose my next step) by randomly sampling from a vector that contains numbers that, when added to the current cell number, lead to the number of an adjacent cell. I have multiple vectors from which to sample as the number of possible directions in which to "walk" differs depending on the position of the current cell (e.g. I can't "walk" to the cell to my lower rigth (=`n + (ncol_dispersal + 1`) if I am currently positioned at the bottom of the raster). The script looks like this so far:

```
library(gdistance)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
setwd("C:/Users/Giaco/Dropbox/Random Walk")   
altdata <- raster("altitude.tif")        
plot(altdata)      
e <- extent(92760.79,93345.79,204017.5,204242.5)    
dispersal_area <- crop(altdata,e)               
plot(dispersal_area)
points(92790.79,204137.5,pch=16,cex=1)              
points(93300.79,204062.5,pch=16,cex=1) 
Pts <- matrix(c(92790.79,204137.5,93300.79,204062.5),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)     
Start <- cellFromXY(dispersal_area,Pts[1,])    
End <- cellFromXY(dispersal_area,Pts[2,])
nrow_dispersal <- nrow(dispersal_area)     
ncol_dispersal <- ncol(dispersal_area)
col_start <- colFromCell(dispersal_area,Start)  
row_start <- rowFromCell(dispersal_area,Start)
col_end <- colFromCell(dispersal_area,End)
row_end <- rowFromCell(dispersal_area,End)
upper_left_corner <- cellFromRowCol(dispersal_area,1,1)     
lower_left_corner <- cellFromRowCol(dispersal_area,14,1)
sample_standard <- c(1,(ncol_dispersal+1),(ncol_dispersal*-1+1))   
sample_top <- c(1,ncol_dispersal,(ncol_dispersal+1))               
sample_bottom <- c(1,(ncol_dispersal*-1+1),(ncol_dispersal*-1))    
sample_left <- c(1,(ncol_dispersal+1),(ncol_dispersal*-1+1))       
sample_upper_left <- c(1,ncol_dispersal,(ncol_dispersal+1))        
sample_lower_left <- c(1,(ncol_dispersal*-1+1),(ncol_dispersal*-1))
Path <- c()
Path[1] <- Start    
n <- Start
counter <- 1




       while (n != End)                             
                {
                n = Start+sample(sample_standard,1) 
                   if (colFromCell(dispersal_area,n)==col_end) {
                   n=End
                   break
                   } else if (n==upper_left_corner) {
                   n = n+sample(sample_upper_left,1)
                   } else if(n==lower_left_corner){
                   n = n+sample(sample_lower_left,1)
                   } else if(colFromCell(dispersal_area,n)==1) {
                   n = n+sample(sample_left,1)
                   } else if(rowFromCell(dispersal_area,n)==1){
                   n = n+sample(sample_top,1)
                   } else if(rowFromCell(dispersal_area,n)==nrow_dispersal) {
                   n = n+sample(sample_bottom,1)
                   } 
                counter <- counter+1
                Path[counter] <- n
                }
```

When I run the script and print the path vector it returns a veeerryy long vector (I always have to stop it as it never finishes computing) which contains only a few different numbers. Why is that ? I have been staring at this all day but I simply can't figure out where i went wrong. There must be something wrong with the while Loop but I don't see it. 
If anyone of you guys could help me out with this I would be really really thankful.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and reproducible example (that also answers your question).

```
library(gdistance)

r <- raster(system.file("external/maungawhau.grd", package="gdistance"))
r <- aggregate(r, 5)
p <- matrix(c(2667531, 6478843, 2667731, 6479227), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)     

start <- cellFromXY(r, p[1,])    
end <- cellFromXY(r, p[2,])

counter <- 1
cell <- start
path <- cell
while (cell != end)  {
    a <- adjacent(r, cell, pairs=F)
    cell <- sample(a, 1)
    path <- c(path, cell)
}
xy <- xyFromCell(r, path)

plot(r)
lines(xy)
```

or

```
cols <- rainbow(nrow(xy))
for (i in 1:nrow(xy)-1) { lines(xy[i:(i+1), ], col=cols[i]) }
```

This is pretty fast on this coarse raster, but it could indeed take a very long time to reach a particular cell on a large raster by random walk.

Perhaps there are function in `gdistance` that are more useful?